# How do I fix Java not enough arguments error (base 64 error)?

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, javabeans

I'm trying to create a java bean that says hello to a String that you pass it and then I'm trying to consume this java bean from a java client that
calls this function and passes a string, but I get an error.

Here are my files:

Package com.servicios

SaludoBean:

```
package com.servicios;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class SaludoBean
 */
@Stateless
public class SaludoBean implements SaludoBeanRemote {

    /**  
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public SaludoBean() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public String saludar(String nombre) {
    return "Hola "+nombre;
    }

}
```

SaludoBeanRemote:

```
package com.servicios;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface SaludoBeanRemote {
    String saludar(String nombre);

}
```

Then on another java project:
package src.com:

```
package com;

 public class ClienteSaludo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingExeption {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         SaludoBeanRemote saludoBean = (SaludoBeanRemote)
InitialContext.doLookup(
 "ModuloEJB/SaludoBean!com.servicios.SaludoBeanRemote");
            System.out.println(saludoBean.saludar("Agustina"));
            System.out.println("Excelente!");   
        }

}
```

I get error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module ClienteSaludo not found
```

I'm using WildFly 24+ server, Eclipse 2021-09

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to make sense given the code you've shown. Do you have a Base64 class being invoked somewhere in your code or build?

Comment: I changed the run target class to my actually main class, now I get a different error. Thank you.